# Is there a way to only allow pip to install universal wheels

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Is there a way to force `pip` to only allow universal or python wheels, and compile locally packages that are only available as binary wheels?

Comment: To what end? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe might sound crazy, but we have an internal pypi server running on a custom ubuntu version and we have another project running on standard ubuntu. So there's chances that the pypi binaries won't be compiled the same way we'd expect on a standard Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

[`pip install --implementation py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-implementation) will only install universal wheels. You will also need to specify what to do about dependencies (if you try running this command without the other required flags there will be an error message that explains what your options are).